# C# - Visual Studio - Find all interface methods with only one reference

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am looking for a way to find every interface methods with only one reference

In other words : methods that are implemented but never called.

My objective is to cleanup dead code.

Thanks,

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You could write a Roslyn Analyzer for this easily enough, I think

Comment: visual studio shows you references to method calls not the interface though would need to do it on implementations

Comment: But you can call Interface method in your code (eg Stream.Read). So you never call (no refs) Filestream.Read. And only but it doesnt mean that you don't need Filestream.Read. Because yoy can define you stream as any stream (memory, file...).

Comment: I think you are looking for code analysis. You have to set code analysis rules to show warnings  and filter out unused methods and fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a command-line tool to do this fairly easily, using Roslyn. Load your project into an `MSBuildWorkspace`, explore the semantic tree to get all methods, then use `SymbolFinder.FindReferencesAsync` to find all references to each method, and print a warning for each method which has no references.

You can also write this as a Roslyn Analyzer. However, you can't use `SymbolFinder` in this context (you don't have a workspace available, and it would be too slow for an analyzer anyway), You can however use `RegisterOperationAction` to look for places which call or reference a method, and at the same time use `RegisterSymbolAction` to look for all methods, then put that together to find all methods which aren't referened.

Something like this is probably a starting point. It care whether a method is defined on an interface or implemented from an interface (that would be fairly easy to add, once you've clarified the rules here), and it's only been superficially tested, but it appears to work.

(You'll need to create a new project using the Analyzer template: follow a tutorial if you've never written an analyzer before).

```
[DiagnosticAnalyzer(LanguageNames.CSharp)]
public class UnusedMethodAnalyzer : DiagnosticAnalyzer
{
    public const string DiagnosticId = "UNUSED";

    private const string Category = "Unused Methods";

    private static readonly DiagnosticDescriptor Rule = new DiagnosticDescriptor(DiagnosticId, "Method is not referenced", "Method '{0}' is not referenced", Category, DiagnosticSeverity.Warning, isEnabledByDefault: true);

    public override ImmutableArray<DiagnosticDescriptor> SupportedDiagnostics { get { return ImmutableArray.Create(Rule); } }

    public override void Initialize(AnalysisContext context)
    {
        context.ConfigureGeneratedCodeAnalysis(GeneratedCodeAnalysisFlags.None);
        context.EnableConcurrentExecution();

        context.RegisterCompilationStartAction(Analyze);
    }

    private void Analyze(CompilationStartAnalysisContext context)
    {
        // Key: IMethodSymbol. Value: true if we've seen a reference to this method, false if we've just seen its definition
        var methods = new ConcurrentDictionary<IMethodSymbol, bool>(SymbolEqualityComparer.Default);

        context.RegisterOperationAction(ctx =>
        {
            methods.AddOrUpdate(((IInvocationOperation)ctx.Operation).TargetMethod, true, (_, _) => true);
        }, OperationKind.Invocation);
        context.RegisterOperationAction(ctx =>
        {
            methods.AddOrUpdate(((IMethodReferenceOperation)ctx.Operation).Method, true, (_, _) => true);
        }, OperationKind.MethodReference);
        context.RegisterSymbolAction(ctx =>
        {
            methods.TryAdd((IMethodSymbol)ctx.Symbol, false);
        }, SymbolKind.Method);

        context.RegisterCompilationEndAction(ctx =>
        {
            foreach (var kvp in methods)
            {
                if (!kvp.Value)
                {
                    var methodSymbol = kvp.Key;
                    var diagnostic = Diagnostic.Create(Rule, methodSymbol.Locations[0], methodSymbol.ToDisplayString(SymbolDisplayFormat.CSharpErrorMessageFormat));
                    ctx.ReportDiagnostic(diagnostic);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it out as soon as possible and mark your answer as accepted once done <3

Comment: It probably won't do quite what you want: I didn't spend very long on it. But it's a starting point that you can refine